# How to chunk matrix data through for loops

Tags: python

Currently I have data in a matrix. I loop through this data like this:

```py
for y in data:
    for x in y:
```

How would I most easily go about chunking this data in squares starting from the left? If the matrix is a 20x20 grid. Let's say I want `chunk size` to be 10x10. Then:

```
chunk0 = y0-9, x0-9
chunk1 = y0-9, x10-19
chunk2 = y10-19, x0-9
chunk3 = y10-19, x10-19
```

How to go about describing this?

Comment: Python supports slicing to select a 1-dimensional range from a sequence (e. g. a list). You could use two slices to address a square (or rectangle) of the matrix. External libraries like numpy even support multidimensional slicing directly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about slicing! Would you care to show some example code? I'm not sure I am able to put it together just yet.

Comment: The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347091/slicing-numpy-array-representing-nested-list) Google result for "python two dimensional list slice". Here's an example without numpy to give you some ideas: Create a test list with four nested lists with values 0-15: `test_list = [[i + j for i in range(4)] for j in range(0, 16, 4)]`, Select the third and fourth values from the second and third rows: `print([row[2:4] for row in test_list[1:3]])`. Numpy slicing would look like this: `test_arr = np.array(test_list); print(test_arr[1:3, 2:4])` which is more succinct.